# postcode.io jQuery plugin syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found an address lookup api, [postcode.io](https://getaddress.io) that I am having trouble getting to work.

On the homepage is a form and jquery plugin for the service, and I have linked the jQuery plugin into my application. A non minified version of the plugin can be found [here](https://getaddress.io/js/jquery.getAddress-2.0.8.js). I am having trouble calling the functions in the script. From the website all you need is:

```
<!-- Add after your form -->
<script>
$('#postcode_lookup').getAddress({
    api_key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',  
    <!--  Or use your own endpoint - api_endpoint:https://your-web-site.com/getAddress, -->
    output_fields:{
        line_1: '#line1',
        line_2: '#line2',
        line_3: '#line3',
        post_town: '#town',
        county: '#county',
        postcode: '#postcode'
    },
<!--  Optionally register callbacks at specific stages -->                                                                                                               
    onLookupSuccess: function(data){/* Your custom code */},
    onLookupError: function(){/* Your custom code */},
    onAddressSelected: function(elem,index){/* Your custom code */}
});
</script>
```

I have managed to get the service to work using my own ajax script, but I am fairly new to javascript therefore would like to understand why the function getAddress() is never called.

I would like to call getAddress() on an onClick() event, therefore assuming I have the necessary HTML in place, what would the javascript look like?

Thanks,

Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `postcode.io`, but I looked to their documentation. `.getAddress` method does not executes directly when you want to know details about postcode.

This method for something like "meta" processing around form submit. I mean, when you added a link to the library, added a form with that `div` and, finally, in lines after the form you have added this:

`$('#id-for-div-with-postcode-input').getAddress({...})`

So, the postcode library prepared your form for submitting data to their endpoints and linking answer lines to specific form fields (see `output_fields` attribute - it's a map of DOM element's ids).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From what I understand from your response, it is only called as an extension of a form submit? Therefore it cannot be called directly?

Comment: Thank you. I have decided to handle this server side rather than using JavaScript.